# How to invoke a shell built-in explicitly?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell-builtin

I want to customize the functionality of `cd` command as per my needs.

I defined the following function - 
`function cd () { cd "$@" && pushd "$@"; }`

The intent of this function is to automatically push the directory onto the stack so that it saves me the effort to manually type `pushd .` every time.

However, the above function is an infinitely recursive function, as the call to `cd` is interpreted to be the function itself and not the `cd` built-in.

How do I reference the `cd` built-in in this function?

I know that aliases can be escaped using `\`. What is the way to escape functions or reference built-ins in a more explicit way?

*Note: I do not want to rename my function to anything else.*

Comment: Why not just `alias cd=pushd`? What do you expect to happen when you cd to something that isn't an absolute path (eg, `cd ../`)?

Comment: @Patrick `pushd` does not support `-P`.  But you are right, as shown in the question the `function cd` looks a bit wrong, as it changed directory twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html) builtin forces a command name to be interpreted as a built-in or external command (skipping alias and function lookup). It is available in all POSIX shells including bash.

```
cd () { command cd "$@" && pushd "$@"; }
```

(Note that this example is a bad one: it doesn't work with relative paths, and you might as well just type `pushd` in the first place.)

In bash and zsh (but not ksh), you can use `builtin` to force a command name to be interpreted as a builtin, excluding aliases, functions and external commands.

Answer (score 24):

Bash has a (builtin) command `builtin`, which does exactly what you need. Replacing `cd` with `builtin cd` in your function will fix the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect when you say you "don't want to rename your function to anything else," you mean that you want to be able to call your function by the same name as the original command.

So, another way to do this that also works for things that aren't built-ins, is to name your function something else, and then define an alias for the wrapped command. This works because the alias doesn't exist in the execution context of your function.

Example wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
function my_wrapper() { wrapped_program $@ && dostuff }
```

And in, e.g., .bash_aliases:

```
source /path/to/wrapper.sh
alias wrapped_program="my_wrapper"
```

But this is pretty hacky. Using `command` is preferable when possible.

Answer (score -1):

For this to work with relative paths, the following would be needed:

```
function cd { 
   dir="$(realpath "$@")"
   command cd "$dir"
   pushd "$dir"
}
```

This assumes you are on a modern enough Linux distro which contains the 'realpath' utility. (RHEL 6 does not for instance). If Perl is available, 'realpath' can be simulated using:

```
! realpath $(pwd) > /dev/null 2>&1  && function realpath {
    perl -e "use Cwd realpath; print realpath(\"$1\") . \"\\n\";"
}
```