# How do I explicitly and safely force the use of a built-in command in bash

Tags: bash, security

There's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102746/how-to-invoke-a-shell-built-in-explicitly) that deals with the 'wrapping' scenario, where you want to replace for example `cd` with a command that calls the builtin `cd`.

However, in light of shellshock et al and knowing that bash imports functions from the environment, I've done a few tests and I can't find a way to safely call the builtin `cd` from my script.

Consider this

```
cd() { echo "muahaha"; }
export -f cd
```

Any scripts called in this environment using `cd` will break (consider the effects of something like `cd dir && rm -rf .`).

There are commands to check the type of a command (conveniently called `type`) and commands for executing the builtin version rather than a function (`builtin` and `command`). But, lo and behold, these can be overridden using functions as well

```
builtin() { "$@"; }
command() { "$@"; }
type() { echo "$1 is a shell builtin"; }
```

Will yield the following:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ cd x
muahaha
$ builtin cd x
muahaha
$ command cd x
muahaha
```

Is there any way to safely force bash to use the builtin command, or at least detect that a command isn't a builtin, without clearing the entire environment?

I realize if someone controls your environment you're probably screwed anyway, but at least for aliases you've got the option to not call the alias by inserting a `\` before it.

Comment: you can run your script using `env` command before, like this: `env -i <SCRIPT.sh>`

Comment: Only if `env` isn't redefined as a function as well. This is terrifying. I first thought that special characters would help -- calling with full path that includes `/`, using `.` to source, and so on. But those can also be used for function names! You *can* redefine any function you want, but it's hard to get back to calling the original command.

Comment: True, but if you're going to run any script on a compromised machine you're screwed anyway. Alternatively, write your script in `#/bin/sh` if this is not default interactive shell.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Olivier D is *almost* correct, but you must set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` before running `unset`. POSIX has a notion of [Special Built-ins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14), and [bash supports this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Builtins.html). `unset` is one such builtin. Search for `SPECIAL_BUILTIN` in `builtins/*.c` in the bash source for a list, it includes `set`, `unset`, `export`, `eval` and `source`.

```
$ unset() { echo muahaha-unset; }
$ unset unset
muahaha-unset
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
$ unset unset
```

The rogue `unset` has now been removed from the environment, if you unset `command`, `type`, `builtin` then you should be able to proceed, but `unset POSIXLY_CORRECT` if you are relying on non-POSIX behaviour or advanced bash features later.

This *does not* address aliases though, so you must use `\unset` (or use [some form of quoting/escaping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) on that word) to be sure it works in interactive shell (or always, in case `expand_aliases` is in effect).

For the paranoid, this *should* fix everything, I think:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
\unset -f help read unset
\unset POSIXLY_CORRECT
re='^([a-z:.\[]+):' # =~ is troublesome to escape
while \read cmd; do 
    [[ "$cmd" =~ $re ]] && \unset -f ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; 
done < <( \help -s "*" )
```

(`while`, `do`, `done` and `[[` are reserved words and don't need precautions. You can't use `=` in an alias or function name, so no precautions needed for setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.)
Note we are using `unset -f` to be sure to unset functions, although variables and functions share the same namespace it's possible for both to exist simultaneously (thanks to Etan Reisner) in which case unset-ing twice would also do the trick. You *can* mark a function readonly, bash does not prevent you unsetting a readonly function up to and including bash-4.2, bash-4.3 does prevent you but it still honours the special builtins when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set.

A readonly `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not a real problem, this is not a boolean or flag its *presence* enables POSIX mode, so if it exists as a readonly you can rely on POSIX features, even if the value is empty or 0. You'll simply need to unset problematic functions a different way than above, perhaps with some cut-and-paste:

```
\help -s "*" | while IFS=": " read cmd junk; do echo \\unset -f $cmd; done
```

(and ignore any errors) or engage in some other [scriptobatics](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

---

Other notes:

- `function` is a reserved word, it can be aliased but not overridden with a function. (Aliasing `function` is mildly troublesome because `\function` *is not* acceptable as a way of bypassing it)
- `[[`, `]]` are reserved words, they can be aliased (which will be ignored) but not overridden with a function (though functions can be so named)
- `((` is not a valid name for a function, nor an alias

Thanks to commenters below for the extra suggestions.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I seems weird to me that bash would default to *not* protecting `unset` et al from being overwritten.

Comment: This needs the `-f` argument to `unset` doesn't it? Otherwise if both a variable and function named the same as a builtin are defined then `unset` will pick the variable to unset first. Also this fails if any of the obscuring functions is set `readonly` doesn't it? (Though that's detectable and can be made a fatal error.) Also this misses the `[` builtin it seems.

Comment: So no, looks like `readonly` isn't a problem... once this uses `\unset -f` at least.

Comment: I don't think `\unset -f unset` makes sense, given it will be done in the read loop. If `unset` is a function your `\unset` would normally resolve to it instead of the builtin, but you can use `\unset` safely so long as POSIX mode is in effect. Explicitly calling `\unset -f` on `[`, `.`, and `:` might be a good idea though, as your regex excludes them.  I would also add `-f` to the `\unset` in the loop, and would `\unset POSIXLY_CORRECT` after the loop, instead of before. `\unalias -a` (after `\unset -f unalias`) also allows one to safely forego the escape on subsequent commands.

Comment: Also, if you wish to securely test for POSIX mode before proceeding and trusting `set`, `unset`, or other builtins/commands, `while [[ ! "${POSIXLY_CORRECT+X}" ]]; do >/dev/null; done` works for me in bash-4.4. While far from ideal due to the freewheeling loop, I couldn't find a way to reliably exit using only reserved words and other non-command constructs. That said, it's preferable to blindly continuing interpretation IMO, as you can't trust `\unset` if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` has been unset and made readonly, causing `POSIXLY_CORRECT=` assignment to fail.

Comment: `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is unset before the loop because I'm lazy and the loop uses non-POSIX features, I'm sure a (more verbose) POSIX compatible alternative would work too. The seemingly superfluous `unset unset` for the same reason. I have amended the regex to include `.` `:` and `[` too, thanks. I don't have a failsafe exit that would work either...

Comment: @AdrianGünter Try: `[[ ${POSIXLY_CORRECT?non-POSIX mode shell is untrusted}x ]]`, this will cause a non-interactive script to exit with the error indicated if the variable is unset, or continue if it is set (empty,  or any value).

Comment: "you must use `\unset`" ... It should be noted that quoting of any character(s) would work to avoid the alias expansion, not just the first. `un"se"t` would work just as well, abeit less readable. "The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias." –[Bash Ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

Answer (score 7):

> I realize if someone controls your environment you're probably screwed anyway

Yes, that. If you run a script in an unknown environment, all manner of things can go wrong, starting with `LD_PRELOAD` causing the shell process to execute arbitrary code before it even reads your script. Attempting to protect against a hostile environment from inside the script is futile.

Sudo has been sanitizing the environment by removing anything that looks like a bash function definition for over a decade. Since [Shellshock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157381/when-was-the-shellshock-cve-2014-6271-7169-bug-introduced-and-what-is-the-pat), other environments that run shell script in a not-fully-trusted environment have followed suit.

You cannot safely run a script in an environment that has been set by an untrusted entity. So worrying about function definitions is not productive. Sanitize your environment, and in doing so variables that bash would interpret as function definitions.

Comment: I disagree with this entirely.  Security is not a binary proposition centered around "sanitized" or "unsanitized".  It's about removing opportunities for exploitation. And unfortunately, the complexity of modern systems means there are many exploitation opportunities that need to be locked down properly.  Many exploitation opportunities center around innocuous-seeming upstream attacks, such as changing the PATH variable, redefining built-in functions, etc.  Offer a single person or program the opportunity to do either, and your entire system is vulnerable.

Comment: @DejayClayton I fully agree with your comment, except for the first sentence, because I don't see how it contradicts my answer in any way. Removing an exploitation opportunity helps, but not removing only half of it where a trivial tweak in the attack allows it to keep working.

Comment: My point is that you can't just "sanitize your environment" and then stop worrying about various attack vectors. Sometimes it pays to "protect against a hostile environment from inside the script." Even if you solve the "function definition" problem, you still have to worry about things such as having a PATH where someone could put a custom script named "cat" or "ls" into a directory, and then any script that invokes "cat" or "ls" instead of "/bin/cat" and "/bin/ls" is effectively executing an exploit.

Comment: @DejayClayton Obviously sanitizing the environment doesn't help with attack vectors that are unrelated to the environment. (For example a script that calls `/bin/cat` in a chroot could be calling anything.) Sanitizing the environment does give you a sane `PATH` (assuming you're doing it right of course). I'm still not seeing your point.

Comment: Considering that PATH is one of the biggest opportunities for exploits, and that many questionable PATH practices are documented as recommended advice even in security blogs, and also considering that sometimes installed applications reorder PATH to ensure that such apps work, I can't see how defensive coding within a script would be a bad idea.  What you consider a sane PATH may in fact be vulnerable to exploits you haven't encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command `unset -f`
to remove the functions `builtin`, `command`, and `type`.

Comment: sorry, `unset() { true; }` takes care of that.

Comment: Damn! And listing defined functions also relies on a builtin. I give up!