Override tr in ~/.bashrc
I'm trying to create a function to translate words via a custom script:
function mean() {
    ~/scripts/translate.sh $1
}

I would prefer the function to be named tr, as it is much shorter and faster to type instead of mean or def.
Any attempts to rename the mean function, eventually collide with tr from GNU Core Utilities (/usr/bin/tr).
I've tried:
alias tr='~/scripts/translate.sh'

or
function tr() {
    ~/scripts/translate.sh $1
}

Causing a new shell to (apparently) run tr with the following output:
bash: export: `input,': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `exiting...': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Vim:': not a valid identifier
': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Vim:': not a valid identifier
': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `


What do you mean by "collide"?

Is the issue that you also want to use the tr utility from coreutils, but that this isn't directly possible if you override the name with a shell function?

collision means that once a new terminal is opened, tr seems to be running with input from the .bashrc file, essentially it was not overridden.

tr is not needed as is (/usr/bin/tr), but I'm also reluctant to mess around with the binary (renaming it for instance)

The function would be the first to be executed before the shell searches for an executable named tr in PATH, see COMMAND EXECUTION

In a new bash shell session and your function named tr is being ignored then the function is not being sourced.

Aliases / functions are properly sourced, it's just when tr is used as a function name, it collides with /usr/bin/tr. Note that if tr function is a simple echo "something", there is no collision. It's the argument that somehow causing tr to run on the .bashrc file itself.

What/which argument is that? like tr(){ tr ...; } ?

function tr() { ~/scripts/translate.sh $1 }

Can you show an invocation that didn't work as you expected it to? The actual command you ran, the output you expected, the error/output you got

translate.sh does not use tr.

Your output doesn't show how you run tr.

I'm guessing your shell start-up scripts, or functions that they define, use tr and with your new non-standard definition of tr these fail.  I would suggest using another name, possibly just t.  Also remember to double-quote that $1 which you use in the function definition.

I can't see how just defining that function could cause those export errors. If they come from your .bashrc, put set -vx; PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE: $LINENO: ' in the top of that file and run the shell again. That should make the shell print each command it runs with filename and line number. Then [edit] your post to include the parts related to those export commands.

@ilkkachu a new shell starts with exactly the same output as in the post. After that, there are lines mostly related to SDKMAN! (which has two special lines at the end of .bashrc), so it is probably the source...

@algonell, so you don't get any trace output? Lines starting with a plus sign showing the commands the shell runs? How do you run the shell that produces those errors?

@ilkkachu I open a new xfce4-terminal tab on Debian 12. SDKMAN! is responsible, dropping it allows the requested override.

When you override the name of the standard utility tr with a function, you run the risk that other uses of that standard utility will call your function instead of the "real" tr (for example, setup code in ~/.bashrc or in other files sourced from there, or later, when specific functions are called in response to what happens in the shell session, for example, to change the content of the primary prompt etc.)
This is what happens in your case, and the strange error messages are caused by some shell function using tr but accidentally getting your translate.sh script rather than the standard tr utility.
Your best option is to not overload the tr name with your private code but instead to find a better name for your utility wrapper.
I would suggest t or TR or Tr or variations on that which do not collide with the name of any already existing utility (note that r may be an alias for "repeat the last command" in some shells; the bash shell's manual suggests making r an alias for fc -s.)
t () { ~/scripts/translate.sh "$1"; }

In general, it is not a good idea to override the names of common utilities with your aliases, shell functions, scripts, etc.  At best, you might encounter random breaking behaviour like what you reported in your question, and at worst, you risk compromising the security of your and other people's systems.
Related reading:

How do I explicitly and safely force the use of a built-in command in bash
What causes this behavior when defining a function named ':'


tr is an interesting case as I already have a custom alias for install (alias install='sudo apt-get install -y'), which is also a part of GNU Core Utilities but works just fine.

@algonell The install utility is much less commonly used, and is unlikely called as a helper utility from your shell session. However, if you tried giving printf, sed or echo new semantics, you should expect to see issues sooner or later.

@Kusalananda I disagree. There are plenty of programs in source code form using GNU autotools (or just POSIX make) that use the install(1) program. Overriding the install program by giving it new semantics is not advisable, just like tr(1) or any such common utilities.

Overriding common utilities with wrappers is often given as an example of what could be done by malicious actors (ex: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188327/367454).

@Vilinkameni "Less commonly used" means just that, not that it's not used. The user overloads the install name with an alias, and has not yet seen their alias used by other interactive shell functions in everyday work. I suggested trying the same thing with a set of utility names that would be more used to show the potential effect of doing things like this. At no time did I insinuate that overriding utility names was advisable. In fact, in my answer, I suggest that they don't do this.

"...and has not yet seen their alias used..." - that doesn't mean that the user won't try to install some program from source which tries to use install(1) and fails, and that easily avoidable issue will require unnecessary troubleshooting. About my second comment, it is related to what the OP is trying to do, not the answer (though IMHO could enhance this answer).

@Vilinkameni Sure, absolutely. It would be an even bigger issue if their install was a shell script in $PATH and not an alias. I was addressing their "but works just fine" comment, and I said that if they wanted to see quicker breakage (because they will otherwise not believe that it's a bad thing to override common utility names with private wrappers that have different semantics), they should try doing that for printf, sed and echo (just examples that I pulled from the top of my head).  My choice of words, "sooner or later", was unfortunate. I meant just "sooner".

@Vilinkameni, but remember that aliases don't work in noninteractive scripts anyway by default, and if they've set them in their bashrc, they don't even get set in noninteractive scripts.

@ilkkachu In Bash, aliases get expanded even in non-interactive shells if shopt -s expand_aliases is executed. Some distributions (ex. Artix Linux) put [[ $- != *i* ]] && return in their /etc/skel/.bashrc or /etc/profile and related files, which could admittedly interfere with this, but only if the user doesn't override that line by putting the previous shopt call above it.

@Vilinkameni, yes, exactly. Aliases get expanded in nonintersctive shells only if someone has explicitly set expand_aliases. It's not on by default in noninteractive scripts. I have a hard time seeing how a conflicting alias would be so likely a problem for an autotools script.

@ilkkachu Alias could be a problem depending on how the user has set up their initialization files (choosing convenience over security as is the intention here) and how a particular program's build scripts are written. If install is called as-is, and without checking whether it is an alias or a function, such build scripts are vulnerable.

@Vilinkameni, sigh. They would have to set $BASH_ENV to point to a file that explicitly sets shopt -s expand_aliases, since scripts don't read the regular init files like bashrc or *profile and aliases aren't inherited into child processes. Sure, they can shoot themselves in the foot. But it won't happen by accident. It would be an issue if they put a command called install in their $PATH, but that wasn't the case here.

@ilkkachu A user could put a line export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc in an initialization file for an interactive Bash shell, or a (badly written, not even necessarily malicious) automated install script could do that without user knowing. All it takes then is to run the installation scripts from that shell. It's a stretch, but possible, so it is better to be proactively safe.

@Vilinkameni To be honest, I'm not entirely sure your discussion here has any bearing on my actual answer. It seems it was sparked from a comment, not the answer itself. If there are no changes that you believe needs to be made to the answer, I will delete the comments later.

@Kusalananda Yes, my comments are replies to the first few comments to the answer, which reveal part of OP's environment and ideas regarding security versus convenience. That's why I believe the reasoning behind not overriding the common utilities should be made more clear and given more context. At least the linked article and the bit about shopt -s expand_aliases should be mentioned.

@Vilinkameni Thank you. I will incorporate that in the text.
