# Using the built-in "time" command in bash rather than the external command

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, time-utility

Working with the `time` command, I came across a situation where I should 
use the built-in `time` rather than the external GNU time command `/usr/bin/time`. So, how can I do this? I saw somewhere that using `enable` and/or `command` would help, but they didn't.

This is a use case:

```
watch "time ls"
```

which uses the external `/usr/bin/time` command, which I don't want! This happens when `time` invokes the internal bash function when I run `time ls` on a terminal, like this:

```
$ time ls
```

Please note that the exact opposite request has been answered here:

- [Make bash use external `time` command rather than shell built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/make-bash-use-external-time-command-rather-than-shell-built-in)

There is a lot of difference with two commands. The internal `time` is more precise (which I want), but the external command has more options (which I do not need).

Comment: `watch 'bash -c "builtin time ls"'` perhaps?

Comment: see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102746/how-to-invoke-a-shell-built-in-explicitly) on how to force bash to use builtins, see answer2 by Petr Utzl: `builtin time` should do the trick.

Comment: @Fiximan, `time` is not a builtin in `bash`, it's a reserved word of the language so you can time pipelines (like `time foo | bar`) or compound commands (like `time for i in...;done`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, `watch` runs your command with `/bin/sh -c '...'` so the output you see is how `/bin/sh` interprets the `time` command. Your `/bin/sh` apparently doesn't have a builtin `time`.

To run the command with a different shell, use the `-x` option to get rid of the default, then add your own explicit invocation of the shell whose builtin you want.

```
watch -x bash -c 'time ls'
watch -x zsh -c 'time ls'
```

No matter how you run `watch`, the command you're watching is not a child of the shell that ran the `watch` command, so that shell's settings aren't directly relevant.