# Where is `exit` defined?

Tags: bash, exit, which

Suppose I want a bash command to do something extra.  As a simple example, imagine I just want it to echo "123" before running.

One simply way to do this would be to alias the command.  Since we still need the original, we can just refer to it by its exact path, which we can find using `which`.  For example:

```
$ which rm
/bin/rm
$ echo "alias rm='echo 123 && /bin/rm'" >> .bashrc
```

This was easy because I was able to look up the path to `rm` using `which`.

However, I am trying to do this with `exit`, and `which` doesn't seem to know anything about it.

```
$ which exit
$ echo $?
1
```

The command did not output a path, and in fact it returned a non-zero exit code, which `which` does when a command is not in `$PATH`.

I thought maybe it's a function, but apparently that's not the case either:

```
$ typeset -F | grep exit
$ echo $?
1
```

So the `exit` command is not defined anywhere as a function or as a command in `$PATH`, and yet, when I type `exit`, it closes the terminal.  So it clearly is defined somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Where is it defined, and how can I call to it explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) is a shell [special built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) command. It was *built* with the shell interpreter, the shell knows about it and can execute it directly without searching anywhere.

On most shells, you can use:

```
$ type exit
exit is a shell builtin
```

You have to read source of the shell to see how its builtin implemented, here is link to source of [`bash` exit builtin](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exit.def).

With `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, to invoke the `exit` built-in explicitly, use `builtin` builtin command:

```
builtin exit
```

See [How to invoke a shell built-in explicitly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102746/how-to-invoke-a-shell-built-in-explicitly) for more details.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh: I'm not sure what I missed. What do you mean *explicitly*? Please feel free to make an editing.

Comment: My answer has covered all the information, I still don't know. If you think that, then your answer should be marked as duplicated.

Comment: @cuonglm Isaac's question has two parts, "Where is it defined?" and "How can I refer to it explicitly?"; you've covered the first, I'll edit your answer to cover the second...

Comment: @StephenKitt: Ah, if OP changed *refer* to *call*, I could get it easier. My bad English.

Comment: Changed it to "call".  Not sure why that is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`exit` is a command of a shell
so any shell - such as `bash` or `ksh` have this command

Comment: It does have the command.  I just want to know where it's defined.  I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: As it was answered more fully upper - it's builtin command
If you need to overwrite - check official FAQ http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ  , G2

Answer (score 1):

The command `exit` belongs to the internals of bash. You can use this to find some help:

```
$ help exit
```

That just show that `exit` is known to the shell, but: what is it?:

```
$ type -a exit
exit is a shell builtin
```

It will not be found as an external file or program, it does not exist outside the shell.

run this: `LESS=+/'^ *exit \[n\]' man bash` to find this:

> exit [n]
>   Cause the shell to exit with a status of n.  If n is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed.  A trap on EXIT is executed before the shell terminates.

It is also [defined as a POSIX builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exit).

To call it explicitly in code, use this:

```
builtin exit
```